# "come back later" error from Steam when trying to play Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

When I try to play Skyrim, I get an error from Steam saying that the game is not available at the moment, and I should try again later. What's going on, and how can I solve this?

Comment: Did you get the game from Steam or from a retailer?

Comment: @James Does not matter it is Steamworks.

Comment: Possibly useful: http://store.steampowered.com/stats/content/  I just saw servers 205 and 230 spike, maybe they're having issues.

Answer (score 7):

Simple solutions first: try restarting steam, or running the game in offline mode. If that doesn't work, [try these other steps from Steam's support page for this problem.](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4595-WEXN-6831)

Comment: I had this error sometimes. Most of the time a restart of Steam was enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Steam is a [DRM System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management). You should read the linked article to understand what Steam actually is.

Your actual problem will probably solve by itself, since this is a temporary error.

However, if you want to speed up the waiting you could verify your game cache and/or switch content servers via the settings.